# Divided operation in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Why i get  error constantly on that?

```
 var rotation:Float= Double(arc4random_uniform(50))/ Double(100-0.2)
```

Actually i try this one too:

```
 var rotation:Double= Double(arc4random_uniform(50))/ Double(100-0.2)
```

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swift has [strict rules about the whitespace around operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/LexicalStructure.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH30-XID_927). Divide '/' is a **binary operator**.

The important rules are:

> - If an operator has whitespace around both sides or around neither
>     side, it is treated as a binary operator. As an example, the +
>     operator in a+b and a + b is treated as a binary operator.
> - If an operator has whitespace on the left side only, it is treated as a
>     prefix unary operator. As an example, the ++ operator in a ++b is
>     treated as a prefix unary operator.
> - If an operator has whitespace on
>     the right side only, it is treated as a postfix unary operator. As an
>     example, the ++ operator in a++ b is treated as a postfix unary
>     operator.

That means that you need to add a space before the `/` or remove the space after it to indicate that it is a binary operator:

```
var rotation = Double(arc4random_uniform(50)) / (100.0 - 0.2)
```

If you want `rotation` to be a Float, you should use that instead of Double:

```
var rotation = Float(arc4random_uniform(50)) / (100.0 - 0.2)
```

There is no need to specify the type explicitly since it will be inferred from the value you are assigning to. Also, you do not need to explicitly construct your literals as a specific type as those will conform to the type you are using them with.

Comment: Damn, I spent an hour FOR A SPACE!.... Thats very stupid:/ AnyWay thank you for nice answer...

Comment: Actually, it's not a bug in the parser. It's in the design of the language. Operators either have no spaces, or spaces on both sides, but not spaces on one side only. Read the Swift language manual, especially bits about user-defined operators.

Comment: @gnasher729 interesting, I didn't realize that, do you have a link to any reference material that states that?

Comment: @gnasher729 never mind, I found it and added it to my answer. thanks for pointing that out